# algebraic closure of an algebraically closed field is itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field.

Recall that $\overline{F}$ is an algebraic closure of $F$ if $\overline{F}/F$ is an algebraic extension and every $f[X]\in F[X]$ can be written as a product of linear factors in $\overline{F}[X].$

---

It is well-known that every algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of $F$ is algebraically closed. 
I am interested in its converse.
More precisely.

> **Question:** Is it true that algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of an algebraically closed field itself? 
>   In particular, does $\overline{F} = F$ hold?

Comment: You can use the following definition for algebraically closed field: "*There are no algebraic extension of $F$ other than itself*". Both are equivalent.

Comment: Certainly, if $F$ is algebraically closed every polynomial can be written in linear factors. Thus, from your definition $\overline{F} = F$ iff $F$ is algebraically closed.